# OnHandleIntent is never called

Tags: android

I have the following `IntentService`:

```
public class HttpMessager extends IntentService {

public HttpMessager() {
    super("is frenk");
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onStartCommand", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Toast.makeText(this, "onDestroy", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onHandleIntent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

And here we have the manifest:

```
<service
        android:name="doesnt.work.well.HttpMessager"
        android:exported="false">
</service>
```

I read on the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#ExtendingIntentService%22documentation%22) that `onStartCommand()` should call the method `onHandleIntent()` and I should not call it directly. Anyway this method (`onHandleIntent()`) is never called while all others are rightly called.

Am I missing something?

**EDIT:** where I launch the service

```
Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), HttpMessager.class);
            i.setAction(HttpMessager.ADD_LAMPS);
            i.putExtra(HttpMessager.LAMPS, lamps);
            getActivity().startService(i);
```

Comment: Please show us the code where you start the service.

Comment: is the path to the service you specified in the manifest correct ? remove `Toast.makeText(this, "onHandleIntent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` . On HandleIntent in executed on a worker thread and you are not supposed to touch the ui there.

Comment: yes, this is the problem, ``OnHandleIntent()`` is executed in another thread, while all others methods are executed in the service thread!! Thx!!

Answer (score 0):

As a starting point, please try removing onStartCommand callback completely and see if it fixes the issue. [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html#onStartCommand(android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int)) documentation mentions explicitly not to override this method and rather implement all your routines in onHandleIntent, which should be called automatically for you once you extend from IntentService.

Comment: In general this is a good point, but they are still calling through to the superclass implementation, so it isn't obvious how this would break things.  It would be better to use log messages than toasts for this sort of purpose though.